# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParserClien.dll File Name

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2017, smo

I have this crazy issue where a SMO operation is failing, and the only difference is this odd file in my bin folder:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParserClien.dll

NOTE: That is not a typo, that is the actual name of the file in the file system.

I don't know what to make of this, I have never seen anything like this in my bin folder before.

The operation that I am doing is :

```
var distributor = new ReplicationServer(conn);
                    if (!distributor.DistributorInstalled)
                    {
                        distributor.InstallDistributor((string)null, distributionDb);
                    }
```

I am using the Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects nuget package with version 140.17177.0.

The fusion log in the exception is :

> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser, Version=14.100.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91  (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///C:/tfs/Back
>   Office/Persistence/ReplicationManagement/Worker/bin/Debug/ LOG:
>   Initial PrivatePath = NULL Calling assembly :
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParserClient, Version=14.100.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91.
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\tfs\Back
>   Office\Persistence\ReplicationManagement\Worker\bin\Debug\Worker.exe.Config
>   LOG: Using host configuration file:  LOG: Using machine configuration
>   file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser,
>   Version=14.100.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/tfs/Back
>   Office/Persistence/ReplicationManagement/Worker/bin/Debug/Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser.DLL.
>   ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing
>   terminated.

The BatchParser file does exist in the bin with the same version specified.  I have one project where this works, and the only difference is the file name in the output.

Comment: Same issue on MS Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3140836/smo-nuget-packages-do-not-work-reliably-due-to-a-gac-dependency-on-sqlserver-batchparser-dll

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar issue. I have an SMO application which uses the Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects nuget package.

The app all runs perfectly on my p.c however when it came to deploying it  and running it on our app server i was getting the error.

*Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.*

To fix the issue I needed to build the project again targeting x86 platform.
I then also had to install the corresponding x86 [C++ Redistributable Package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784)

Comment: Installing the x86 package resolved this issue for me. Seems the issue has to do with the nuget package not having a target for AnyCpu. See discussion here. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32898796-smo-nuget-packages-do-not-work-reliably-due-to-a-g

Comment: Right - the VC++ 2013 dependency is listed under "System Requirements" on this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/installing-smo?view=sql-server-ver15 (but not on the NuGet page!)

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio 2017 download this nuget package

[image: Open PM Console and paste below line]

```
Install-Package Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects -Version 140.17283.0
```

[More Information about latest builds](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and i had to set my Platform target to be Any CPU **and** to check Prefer 32-bit.